# What is a Slurry in Microbiology?

Tags: microbiology

I have been reading this article and they refer to this thing called 'slurries' that can be made from soil samples. This is in the context of being some sort of microbiological method.

"slurries can be made from these soil samples"

Does anyone know what this is? When googling it, I can not find a clear answer to what the method does.

Comment: It's not a microbiological term; it's used according to the [standard definition of the word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slurry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, microbiologist use this term to describe the process of culturing microorganisms from soil. You make a 'slurry' which has both growth media and the soil (which would fall under the english definition of a slurry) and incubate it waiting for growth. Media(Liquid) + soil = Slurry

Answer (score 1):

A slurry can also be used to mean a semi-melted ice water mix. Most people would call it ‘slush’, but I’ve come across it in some protocols before (can’t think of a reference to provide though, so it’ll depend on your particular context).